Uvicorn service is't working on remote host
I've simple service on Python FastApi and I've installed and started the Uvicorn service on win server 2016 host with cmd command "uvicorn main:app". Service was started on 127.0.0.1:8000. In local server browser it's works normal, but when I try to use this service on the remote terminal browser I catch err_connection_refused, telnet application can't connect to server_ip 8000 too. I temporary switched off server firewall, but have the same problem. Don't know where I was wrong, what should I check? Please help. Thanks
I've switched of server FW
I've checked the Server service on in Win Services

If you're binding to localhost (127.0.0.1), the daemon will only be accessible through the local loopback interface on the same computer. You'll need to bind to the ip of the interface you want to make the daemon available on. You can use --host as an argument to uvicorn to change the ip you're binding to.

Try using uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0

Great uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 works well, thanks
